# Dual Gang Potentiometer Replacement

Tags: potentiometer

I asked a similar question a few days ago which I got my answer to, but I'm asking a new question now which is unrelated. I'm thinking of buying this audio amplifier: http://www.ebay.com/itm/191879583686
It has a dual gang potentiometer with 6 pins that I believe is acting as a voltage divider, which I want to replace with a wheel potentiometer. The only wheel pots that I believe to exist are 3 pin and 5 pin. If I used the 3 pins, I would have to use two of them (which I don't want). I'm not sure how the 5 pin ones work though, or whether or not it could be replace with the dual gang 6 pin pot. The wheel I'm looking at is this one: http://www.ebay.com/itm/122360414148
It says its a dual dial, though I'm not sure if that's the same as a dual gang. If it is, why does this one only have 5 and how could I replace the 6?

Comment: What does the datasheet say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same as a dual gang, except in some cases, where there are 5, each "gang" shares a terminal (probably #1). So you will have two "input," two "output," and one shared ground. You will need a data sheet or multimeter to figure out which is which for sure.

Comment: Okay, so I should have no problem replacing it with a 5 pin wheel as long as I know which pin is which?

Comment: That's right. And another note... If you look at the image of the "bottom" of the amp, you can see the 6 pins of the pot - two of which are connected together. Your 5-pin pot just does that same thing internally.